# How to add a custom product to cart using PHP

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cart, custom-options, addtocart

Please bear with me, I'm new to Magento and PHP.

I've been looking for hours for this but unfortunately I cannot make it to work. All other questions made didn't explained where to get the variables.

Can someone explain to me how to get this working?
I don't know which parameters to pass to the code to add the product to the cart...

What I need to do is to include a custom product to the cart after a person chose it from different options on a `form`. I have the `form` working.

I guess I need to modify the code below with ID's and such, but I have no idea where to get the data I need to fill in...

```
// Add a product (simple); id:12,  qty: 1
$cart->addProduct(12, 1);

// Add a product with custom options
$productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$param = array(
    'product' => $productInstance->getId(),
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => array(
        234 => 'A value'  // Custom option with id: 234
    )
);
```

This is what I have:

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php'; 

umask(0);  
Mage::init('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));  

// Get customer session
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 

// Get cart instance
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$cart->init();

// Add a product (simple); id:12,  qty: 1
$cart->addProduct(12, 1);

// Add a product with custom options
$productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$param = array(
    'product' => $productInstance->getId(),
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => array(
        234 => 'A value'  // Custom option with id: 234
    )
);
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($param);
$cart->addProduct($productInstance, $request);

// Set shipping method
$quote = $cart->getQuote();
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')->save();               

// update session
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

// save the cart
$cart->save();
```

---Edit---

This is the message I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Please specify the product required option(s).' in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\app\Mage.php:595 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php(284): Mage::throwException('Please specify ...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\mixform\form.php(71): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\app\Mage.php on line 595
```

Comment: This seems wrong: `'options' => array(
        234 => 'A value'  // Custom option with id: 234
    )`
should be 
`'option' => 'value'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993483/magento-get-custom-option-value-details-from-option-value-id

Now I'm able to check what's the option and custom option ID with only the product ID.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of difficult to answer without knowing what kind of custom options you've set up for this product. I suggest logging `$param` from the cart controller add action.

Enable logging in system configuration, temporarily place this code in `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction`, and go add the product with the custom options to the cart on the frontend.

```
class Mage_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    ...
    public function addAction()
    {
        ...
        Mage::log($params);  // Place this code
        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Examine what `$params` looks like and build it accordingly in your script.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do it and I was trying to get the option and custom option ID. Thanks though.

Comment: So I found this that solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993483/magento-get-custom-option-value-details-from-option-value-id